# Program freezes during run at While loop

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

The program I am writing needs to read 4 lines of data from a text file containing an ID, Name, Level, and Salary for an employee. It then needs to create a formatted email address and print all of this to standard output. The text file can contain an unknown number of employees, so a while loop must be used with the hasNext() method to confirm there is more data to read.

My program freezes (using Dr. Java) as soon as the while loop begins, and I cant figure out why.

Here is my code so far

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
File file = new File("employeeInput.txt");

if (file.exists()) {  //check if file exists
  
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);  //opens file
  
  String companyName = inputFile.nextLine();
  
  System.out.println(companyName);
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("----------------------------");
  
  while (inputFile.hasNext()); {
  
  String studentID = inputFile.nextLine();
  System.out.println(studentID);
  
  String studentName = inputFile.nextLine();
  System.out.println(studentName);
  
  String employeeLevel = inputFile.nextLine();
  System.out.println(employeeLevel);
  
  double salary = inputFile.nextDouble();
  System.out.println(salary);
  
  }
  
  inputFile.close();
  
  
}
  
  else {
    
    System.out.println("The file employeeInput.txt does not exist");
    
  }
}
```

}

I understand this code is not complete and does everything the program needs to, but I do not get why it's freezing at the while loop..

Any help or advice would be appreciated. This is my first class ever in programming language, so go easy on me :)

Comment: `while (inputFile.hasNext());` That is a loop on its own. The semi-colon means you have an empty loop body... and seeing as you don't *consume* anything from `inputFile`, if it starts off with `hasNext` returning true, it'll keep returning true. You should remove the semi-colon if you want the brace after it to indicate "this is the start of the loop body".

Comment: Thanks Jon! So that allowed the program to advance on and read the first employees data and prints out as expected, but now its producing a inputmismatchexception error when it reaches the next employee's Level. It reads the ID and Name just fine from the text file. For reference the file is something like this

HV2323
John Smith
B
100000.0
HV12333
Jane Smith
B
10000.0

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't an interacting debugging service. I've explained the problem you presented in this question. I'd suggest deleting the question as it's basically just a typo (or not understanding the syntax of while loops). Now take a while to try to research/diagnose your *next* issue, and ask a new question with all the relevant information if you can't solve it yourself.